# Sandbox not found in eherium studio

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

I am using ethereum studio from docker image , I am trying to run contracts but it gives error :
"Could not run sandbox. No Sandbox found"

I also checked in sandbox tab no sandbox environment is there

How can I configure it?

Answer (score 0):

The [GitHub project site](https://github.com/ether-camp/ethereum-studio-docker) says:

> The image is broken since the ethereum sandbox doesn't support the latest solc. Fixing it.

That was 8 months ago and hasn't been updated since.

Comment: Thanx for the update  , how can I start working on contracts then  ?
I tried using truffle , contracts were compiled and linked to private network 
but transactions could not happen